# Получить сообщения с директа Instagram

Tags: php, api, instagram

Как получить личные сообщения с помощью АПИ инстаграмм?
[Здесь](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) искал, не нашел. Может не там ищу?
Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: так в инстаграме же нет вроде лс.

Comment: есть директ называется)

Comment: instagram-private-api библиотека npm у меня получилось получать и отправлять сообщения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Нет такого в [permission scopes](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/).

Comment: А если не через АПИ, а просто парсить страницу? Есть такая возможность?

Comment: А на странице разве отображаются direct-сообщения?

Comment: через официальное апи нет, а вообще фича есть. надо понять просто какой запрос шлется.